# Are the three wraps around the middle finger (tefillin shel yad) halacha?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilin, hands-fingers

There is a custom by many to wrap the strap of the tefillin shel yad around the middle finger three times. Is this halacha or is this a common minhag that is rarely broken and nearly universal?

---

**Note:** I seem to remember a question like this already floating around. I tried looking for it but I couldn't turn anything up. If it does already exist, could someone please point it out to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rambam (Responsa ed. Blau #159) and Rosh (Responsa 3:2) cited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53718/8775), write that it is not a necessary part of the mitsvah